# dracut Warning: Unable to process initqueue

Tags: linux, boot, grub, kernel, initramfs-tools

I'm on Mageia2 x86_64 with kernel 3.3.8-desktop-2.mga2.
The kernel boot normally.

My laptop is old so i need the old kernel for better compatibility and functionality. The problem is that the old kernel 2.6.38.7-desktop-1.mga of Mageia1 won't boot after upgrade from Mageia1 to Mageia2.

I tried to change the grub "root" parameter from root=UUID... (the uuid is correct i verified with blkid) to root=/dev/sda1 but the error it's the same:

```
udevd[186]: could not find module by name='8139too'

dracut Warning: Unable to process initqueue  
dracut Warning: /dev/... does not exist
```

Dropping to debug shell

The "..." mean sda1 or the disk/by-label when i use uuid. With the debug shell i discovered that in the /dev dir there is no /dev/sdaX device nor /dev/sr0 or/dev/disk directory and seem like the physical device are not loaded at boot.

I tried also to recreate the initrd by the following command:

```
dracut -l -f --hostonly /boot/initrd-2.6.38.7-desktop-1.mga.img 2.6.38.7-desktop-1.mga
```

with the following output:

```
I: *** Including module: dash ***
I: *** Including module: i18n ***
E: i18n_vars not set!  Please set up i18n_vars in  configuration file.
E: No KEYMAP.
I: *** Including module: rpmversion ***
I: *** Including module: plymouth ***
E: libkmod: index_mm_open: major version check fail: 65537 instead of 2953311319
E: libkmod: index_mm_open: major version check fail: 65537 instead of 2953311319
I: *** Including module: kernel-modules ***
E: libkmod: index_mm_open: major version check fail: 65537 instead of 2953311319
E: libkmod: index_mm_open: major version check fail: 65537 instead of 2953311319
E: libkmod: index_mm_open: major version check fail: 65537 instead of 2953311319
E: libkmod: index_mm_open: major version check fail: 65537 instead of 2953311319
E: libkmod: index_mm_open: major version check fail: 65537 instead of 2953311319
E: libkmod: index_mm_open: major version check fail: 65537 instead of 2953311319
E: libkmod: index_mm_open: major version check fail: 65537 instead of 2953311319
E: libkmod: index_mm_open: major version check fail: 65537 instead of 2953311319
E: libkmod: index_mm_open: major version check fail: 65537 instead of 2953311319
E: libkmod: index_mm_open: major version check fail: 65537 instead of 2953311319
E: libkmod: index_mm_open: major version check fail: 65537 instead of 2953311319
E: modprobe: tools/kmod-modprobe.c:550: print_action: Assertion `kmod_module_get_initstate(m) == KMOD_MODULE_BUILTIN' failed.
E: libkmod: index_mm_open: major version check fail: 65537 instead of 2953311319
E: libkmod: index_mm_open: major version check fail: 65537 instead of 2953311319
E: libkmod: index_mm_open: major version check fail: 65537 instead of 2953311319
E: libkmod: index_mm_open: major version check fail: 65537 instead of 2953311319
E: libkmod: index_mm_open: major version check fail: 65537 instead of 2953311319
E: libkmod: index_mm_open: major version check fail: 65537 instead of 2953311319
E: libkmod: index_mm_open: major version check fail: 65537 instead of 2953311319
E: libkmod: index_mm_open: major version check fail: 65537 instead of 2953311319
E: libkmod: index_mm_open: major version check fail: 65537 instead of 2953311319
E: libkmod: index_mm_open: major version check fail: 65537 instead of 2953311319
E: libkmod: index_mm_open: major version check fail: 65537 instead of 2953311319
E: libkmod: index_mm_open: major version check fail: 65537 instead of 2953311319
E: libkmod: index_mm_open: major version check fail: 65537 instead of 2953311319
E: libkmod: index_mm_open: major version check fail: 65537 instead of 2953311319
E: libkmod: index_mm_open: major version check fail: 65537 instead of 2953311319
E: libkmod: index_mm_open: major version check fail: 65537 instead of 2953311319
E: libkmod: index_mm_open: major version check fail: 65537 instead of 2953311319
E: libkmod: index_mm_open: major version check fail: 65537 instead of 2953311319
E: libkmod: index_mm_open: major version check fail: 65537 instead of 2953311319
E: libkmod: index_mm_open: major version check fail: 65537 instead of 2953311319
E: libkmod: index_mm_open: major version check fail: 65537 instead of 2953311319
E: libkmod: index_mm_open: major version check fail: 65537 instead of 2953311319
E: libkmod: index_mm_open: major version check fail: 65537 instead of 2953311319
E: libkmod: index_mm_open: major version check fail: 65537 instead of 2953311319
I: *** Including module: resume ***
I: *** Including module: rootfs-block ***
I: *** Including module: terminfo ***
I: *** Including module: udev-rules ***
I: Skipping udev rule: 50-udev.rules
I: Skipping udev rule: 95-late.rules
I: Skipping udev rule: 50-firmware.rules
I: *** Including module: usrmount ***
I: *** Including module: base ***
I: *** Including module: fs-lib ***
I: *** Including module: shutdown ***
I: Skipping program kexec as it cannot be found and is flagged to be optional
I: *** Including modules done ***
I: Wrote /boot/initrd-2.6.38.7-desktop-1.mga.img:
I: -rw------- 1 root root 6473315 Dec 24 17:57 /boot/initrd-2.6.38.7-desktop-1.mga.img
```

But at boot time only the error related the model 8139too it's disappeared.

Someone can help me ?
Thanks

Comment: Well constructed first question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related the error reported in the libkmod error showed in the above post.

```
E: libkmod: index_mm_open: major version check fail: 65537 instead of 2953311319
```

I don't know why but the modules provided in the folder /lib/modules/2.6.38.7-desktop-1.mga and attached to the initrd are not loaded correcly. Indeed with dracut boot i can see a lot of unknown symbol error for example when the module pata_atiixp is loaded that is used to access the disk and the related rootfs. 
So this is why the rootfs isn't mounted at boot time.

I tried to create an initrd without dracut the official adopted in Mageia2 with the old mkinitrd. I tried first with **mkinitrd-mkinitrd** command in Mageia2 and then with **mkinitrd** from an installation of Mageia1. Both ramdisk was built with modules pata_atiixp, ext4, ehci-hcd, ohci-hcd and others modules needed to boot.

The result was the same the kernel boot with this two initrd but when the kdm login screen is reached i can't use the keyboard and the mouse/touchpad or every hid attached to the usb ports. As work around i edited the xorg.conf file putting this line:

```
Option "AutoAddDevices" "False"
```

and manually added two **InputSection** one for keyboard and one for synaptics touchpad. After reboot only the keyboard was enabled and at least i was able to login and discover that the wireless module, the sound card module a lot of others are not loaded. Trying to load manually this module give the above libkmod error. Probably the same happen to the keyboard modules and mouse modules that are not loaded and this is why i was unable to use them without the xorg.conf workaround.

However i discoverd also that suspend and hibernate won't work any more with the old kernel as in Mageia1. I started this fight because i thought that with old kernel this functionality probably will come back but this was not the result. The new library of Mageia2 used to the Power Management, especially **e2ram** and **e2disk** seem to be incompatible with my hardware doesn't matter if the kernel is 2.6.38 or 3.3.8 and now another question arise:

Why i'm not able to suspend or hibernate my laptop with the old kernel ?

and

what does mean the libkmod error ?

Maybe it's related the "version magic" of the modules ? 
But this is very strange because it's a precompiled kernel taken from the official repository and used without problem in Mageia1.